# MVC3 - how can I override the template/behavior of EditorFor IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, editortemplates

I would like to globally replace the default editor with my own.  The default just iterates and creates editors for each item in the model.

This doesn't give you control over the html structure (eg whether to use li elements or a table etc). Also I would like the default editor to include add/remove buttons for all enumerable collections of any type (or at least turn that on or off with an attribute)

I will also be overriding the defaultmodelbinder so I can add extra features - I already know how to do this, just stuck with the template part.

Before you ask, I have already tried creating an editor template for type IEnumerable but it is picky about rendering, even if I specify the template name.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you need only edit the default object template and do your own rendering.

Implementations of the default template are available in the MVC3 futures source download on codeplex at http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases

You can also read Brad Wilsons article on the subject (it's for MVC2, but it still applies) at http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html